# Object 'sef' not found in R corr.test

Tags: r

I am attempting to run the corr.test equation in R, with code that my professor submitted and tested on his system. Unfortunately, when I run it I am getting an error that "object sef not found".

This is confounding both my professor and I, and having done a thorough search, we're not sure how to address this.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Edit: Here is the code I am using:

```
trendan1 <- read.table("trendan1.for.R.dat", header=TRUE, na.strings=".")
head(trendan1)
tail(trendan1)
attributes(trendan1)
is.matrix(trendan1)

id <- trendan1$id
famenv1 <- trendan1$famenv1
famenv2 <- trendan1$famenv2
famenv3 <- trendan1$famenv3
conf1 <- trendan1$conf1
conf2 <- trendan1$conf2
conf3 <- trendan1$conf3

trendan1dataset1 <- cbind(id,famenv1,famenv2,famenv3,conf1,conf2,conf3)
attributes(trendan1dataset1)
is.matrix(trendan1dataset1)
is.data.frame(trendan1dataset1)

require("psych")
describe(trendan1dataset1[,2:7])
print(describe(trendan1dataset1[,2:7]), digits=6)  


famave <-  (1*famenv1 + 1*famenv2 + 1*famenv3)/3
famlin <-  -1*famenv1 + 0*famenv2 + 1*famenv3
famquad <-  1*famenv1 - 2*famenv2 + 1*famenv3;

trendandataset2 <- cbind(famenv1,famenv2,famenv3,famave,famlin,famquad)
print(describe(trendandataset2), digits=6)

hist(famenv1)
boxplot(famenv1)
abline(h=mean(famenv1)) 
qqnorm(famenv1,ylab="famenv1")  
qqline(famenv1)                
shapiro.test(famenv1)

hist(famenv2)
boxplot(famenv2)
abline(h=mean(famenv2)) # add mean to the boxplot
qqnorm(famenv1,ylab="famenv2")  
qqline(famenv2)                
shapiro.test(famenv2)

corvars1 <- cbind(famenv1,famenv2,famenv3)


cor(corvars1,use = "everything", method = "pearson")
cov(corvars1,use = "everything")
sscp1 <- t(corvars1)%*%(corvars1) #Matrix multiplcation
sscp1

rc1 <- corr.test(corvars1, 
use="pairwise",method="pearson",adjust="holm",alpha=.05, ci=FALSE) 
attributes(rc1)
print(rc1$p, digits=6)
```

Comment: can you give the data and code you used (for the data, at least show what the structure is)

Comment: Edit the question (preferably with code formatting); don't post code as a comment.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines: <https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask> in the help documentation, and <https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic>.  Remember, you also need to include [Minimal, complete, verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described. When done, click `edit` to edit your question so that we may help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that sometimes happens when you do not evaluate confidence interval. It should be fixed if u **change the option to ci=TRUE**, or simply delete this option as the default is ci=TRUE.